# TypeORM: Load relations with only certain specified fields

Tags: typeorm, database-relations

Despite much research and trial and error, I unfortunately do not yet have an elegant solution for the following use case:
A user has several posts, which is correctly implemented as a **one-to-many relationship**. I want to load the user with all his posts, but **not all attributes** of the posts, **only certain ones**.

*Approach 1: Find*

```js
await this.usersRepository.find({relations: ['posts']});
```

Here I can't define a corresponding select restriction anywhere.

*Approach 2: QueryBuilder*

```js
await this.usersRepository.createQueryBuilder('user')
.leftJoinAndSelect('user.posts', 'posts').select('posts.title').getMany();
```

Here I define the restriction supposedly, but the select seems to refer only to user.

Am I missing something? Or is there no intended solution for my use case?

I would be very grateful for help, thanks guys!

TypeORM version 0.2.22

Answer (score 8):

I was able to get the appropriate results you're expecting. You don't have to use `getRawMany` if you don't want to, and need the nested objects like I do from `getMany` and `getManyAndCount` in the way my schema is built up.

That being said, if you have the correct `OneToMany` relation setup in your entity

```js
@OneToMany(type => Post, post => post.user)
posts: Post
```

Then you should be able to hit

```js
const userResults: any = await getRepository(entities.User)
    .createQueryBuilder('user')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('user.posts', 'posts')
    .select([
        'posts.name',
        'user.id'
    ])
    .getMany()
```

Which results in

```
userResults User {
  id: 3,
  posts: [ Post { name: 'asdfasdfasdf' }, Post { name: 'asdf' } ] }
```

Hope this helps, and/or you figured this out.

Answer (score 1):

Use  getRawMany() instead of getMany() if you want to select some fields

try

```js
await this.usersRepository.createQueryBuilder('user')
.leftJoinAndSelect('user.posts', 'posts')
.select('posts.title')
.getRawMany();
```

For more info :
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#getting-values-using-querybuilder

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it basically works!

But not quite as hoped for:
1. you have to specify all properties explicitly in select, which becomes a lot very quickly. By default I want the whole user and only certain fields of posts.
2. for example, the property names of the post change to posts_title. What I wanted would be the following, as usual in TypeORM with relations:



    "user": {
      "username": "test",
      "email": "test@test.com",
      "posts": [
        {"title": "title 1"}, 
        {"title": "title 2"}
      ]
    }

I'm afraid that's not gonna happen, is it?

Comment: 'users.*' might do the work.

Answer (score 0):

if you want post title and body alone, do this

```
await this.usersRepository.find({
  relations: ['posts'], 
  select: {
    post: {
      title: true,
      body: true,
    }
  }
});
```